# How to exclude null properties from marshalling with Grails XML marshaller

Tags: grails

When marshalling to XML in Grails 2.3.5, I want null properties to be excluded from the XML.

Currently code like this

```
if ( myObj.someProp == null ) log.info("yeap, it's null")
render myObj as XML
```

will output "yeap, it's null" to the log and then render XML that looks like

```
<myObj>
    <someProp />
</myObj>
```

but what I want is

```
<myObj>
</myObj>
```

Or simply (if no other properties are present)

```
<myObj />
```

Can Grails be configured to exclude null properties from marshalling?

Also, using

```
def xml = myObj as XML
if ( myObj.someProp == null ) {
    xml.excludes = ["someProp"]
}
render xml
```

won't work in all cases because sometimes it's a list of `results` where the items in the list may have null properties.

**UPDATE**

I tried @dmahapatro's suggestion by adding the following code to `BootStrap.groovy`

```
    XML.registerObjectMarshaller(MyObj) {
        it.properties.findAll { it.value != null }
    }
```

with the appropriate import statements.

The results are XML that is incorrect:

```
<myObj>
    <entry key="someProp">non-null value</entry>
</myObj>
```

Now the properties are no longer the names of tags.  Instead, a generic "entry" tag is used, because Grails is seeing a Map instead of a domain object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to exclude tags for null values from the output using the built-in converters and marshallers.  Having read the Grails source code there are two relevant classes that control this behavior, neither of which is configurable to behave differently.

The first is the marshaller class `DomainClassMarshaller` in `grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/converters/marshaller/xml/` and the relevant lines are

```
xml.startNode(propertyName);
if (!property.isAssociation()) {
    // Write non-relation property
    Object val = beanWrapper.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
    xml.convertAnother(val);
}
```

This starts the node for the property (regardless of its value) then calls `xml.convertAnother` on the value.

The second relevant line of code is the `convertAnother` method in `XML.java` of `grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/grails`

```
if (o == null) {
    // noop
}
```

Which does nothing if the value is null (leaving the tag empty) and references no configuration options to behave differently.

Therefore, the only way to get the desired behavior is to implement it from scratch and register the custom marshaller/converter as @dmahapatro suggested.

Since the OP asked how to do this with the Grails XML Marshaller, the correct answer is simply: it cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`registerObjectMarshaller`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/converters/XML.html#registerObjectMarshaller%28java.lang.Class,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) to modify that behavior.

```
//Bootstrap.groovy
import grails.converters.XML
import my.package.MyObj

XML.registerObjectMarshaller(MyObj) {
    it.properties.findAll { it.value != null }
}
```

**UPDATE**
In order to avoid the entry tags because of map representation of domain class, the object marshaller can be easily transformed to get expected result as below:

```
XML.registerObjectMarshaller(Author) {obj, xml ->
    xml.attribute 'id', "$obj.id"
    xml.build {
        obj.properties.each {
            if(it.value != null) {
                "$it.key" it.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and the results are incorrect... I'll update my question with the results.

Comment: Updated the answer to get the expected result. I hope this is what you were looking for. @Jason (working for a long time in JSON, it is tricky to switch back and look through an XML perspective) :)

Comment: :)  Okay... that works for _some_ controllers.  However, when the domain object has a composite key, this will not marshall the composite key properly.  I'm really looking for a minimalist solution that allows Grails to do all the work it usually does but just change this one aspect: exclude null properties from the XML.  I do not want to replace the existing Grails marshalling code because any replacement will likely fail to account for everything Grails already handles well.